# ImageMagick command line to extract Gimp entered Metadata info

Tags: imagemagick, metadata, gimp

Using the [Gimp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GIMP) Metadata Editor (Image > Metadata > Edit Metadata) the users can insert info into the files.

[image: Metadata Editor]

I assume that with some ImageMagick command line I can extract this info. I have not been able to determine how.

Comment: ImageMagick does not allow you to write to EXIF or other meta data other than the label and comment fields. Use Exiftool. See https://exiftool.org

Comment: fmw42 What are 'label' & 'comment' fields called in GIMP? How does one use ImageMagick to extract them?

Comment: I do not know what GIMP calls them nor how to extract them. In ImageMagick, you can add comments (or labels) by `convert image -set comment "some comment" image` and to read it back, you can do `convert image -format "%c" info:`

Answer (score 1):

Use [Specific Profile Percent Escape Prefixes](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/escape.php) with [format switch](https://imagemagick.org/script/escape.php).

```
identify -format %[EXIF:tag]
```

- Artist

or

```
identify -format %[IPTC:dataset:record]
```

- 2:05  Object Name (Title)
- 2:15  Category
- 2:25  Keywords
- 2:105  Headline

may address the issue.